# can server 2012 R2 be used in server 2008 R2 terminal server farm

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, windows-terminal-services

I have currently have 3 server 2008 R2 servers forming a server farm with a separate server 2008 R2 session broker.

I am familiar with adding servers to the farm using active directory and joining the "session broker computers" group.

This works fine for my 2008 R2 servers, with the 2012 R2 server I can join the group without any errors but the session broker refuses to recognize it and assign users to this server.

I then tried making the 2012 R2 server into the session broker instead with all the 2008 R2 servers members. That did not pan out either.

There was nothing online about how to go about this so I figured I would ask if anyone knows if this is possible before I keep struggling with it.

Comment: Your RDS CAL will not fit. Why you didn't downgraded ?

Comment: AFAIK, the 2012+ RDS farm protocols are completely incompatible with 2008r2.  I don't have a good reference handy though.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I have new CALs for it. The 2012 R2 one is a massive G9 server set-up with the idea that it will be able to handle the full load of the 3 2008 servers. I am trying to ease the users onto it so ideally it would just be a member of the farm until everyone moves over and I can see that it will support all users. Made sense to get the latest and greatest on one server.

Comment: @Zoredache thanks, I've given up on that strategy now... I'll take that as an answer if you post it.

Comment: If you got the CAL, then just slowly change the user .rdp file to slowly migrate them there, as a standalone server (in a new cluster is up to you)